# How to find maximum sum in a list whose value is less than or equal to n?

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

mylist = [5,7,12,18]
n = 20
How to find maximum value of sum of list elements in mylist so that the sum of the elements are less than or equal to n efficiently?

Comment: This is not a python problem. Have you tried anything (e.g. take the Wikipedia entry that discusses computational complexity of algorithms to solve this at great length)?

Comment: Sound like discrete knapsack problem, kindly describe the problem with an example(your have not given the solution of the example in question) or some mathematical expression.